# Want to sell images online on wordpress but slow image loading issues

Tags: media-library

I wish to sell images, videos and music online but if I add the media files in WordPress, the website becomes slow. IS it possible to add a library? where I can upload thousands of images and videos without slowing down my WordPress site and linking it to the website?

Comment: It is possible, a lot of sites have thousands of items in the media library, you should not need to make any changes to allow this

Comment: Are you on shared hosting, are you using a third-party commercial theme that has a ton of code bloat and features you're not using?  The speed issues could be any number of things.

Answer (score 0):

Use ShortPixel to optimize photos, or a CDN to server them in a faster way.
For low-cost solution offload media files to S3 via a plugin.